# How To Create And Display A Timer In XNA Game Studio

Tags: c#, timer, xna

I am creating a Board-Game style game in XNA Game Studio. One of the "mini-games" inside of it requires a timer. I have tried various methods but, I am stumped. If anyone can help, I would also like it to be activated by a button. This is the code I have currently:

```
if (orbStart)
{
    int counter = 10;
    int limit = 50;
    float countDuration = 2f; //every  2s.
    float currentTime = 0f;
    currentTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; 

    if (currentTime >= countDuration)
    {
        counter++;
        currentTime -= countDuration;    
    }

    if (counter >= limit)
    {
        //Stuff
    }

    }
}
```

`OrbStart` being the boolean activated by the button. Any help will be great!

Comment: I can't understand what your timer should do, if you can explain me in words I'll try to answer you.

Comment: It's not clear what every variable in this code means, but `counter` is a local variable which will always have the same value every time this function is called. Therefore it does not "count" anything. You should use a field of the class to store the current "counter" or time elapsed.

Comment: I cut out all the stuff that had nothing to do with the timer, just to clear some confusion. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first create global variables, for example:

```
bool isTimerOn = false;
float counter = 10; // 10 seconds
```

Then you should change isTimerOn to true when user presses your button, hope you know how to do it. Next step- inside your update method, substract elapsed time from the last tick from counter's value and check whether the time is up:

```
if (isTimerOn)
{
   counter -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds;
   if (counter <= 0)
   doSomething();
}
```

Oh, I've noticed you wanted help with your button too. So first of all, you should create a Recentagle inside which your button will be placed:

```
Rectangle button = new Rectangle(50, 60, 100, 30);
```

This code means your buttons upper left point is located at (50, 60), it's width is 100 and it's height is 30. You can really read how to drawsprite at this location everywhere, as it was discussed for a couple of times here.
To check whether user clicks our button, just read about how to handle gestures and check whether tap's position is inside our rectangle, here's the code:

```
while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
   GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
   switch (gs.GestureType)
   {
     case GestureType.Tap:
       if (button.Contains((int) gs.Position.X, (int) gs.Position.Y))
          isTimerOn = true;
     break;
   }
}
```

To make it work there's just one more thing- you have to enable tap gesture. Inside `LoadContent()` method add:

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap;
```

Comment: When I drew the timer with spriteBatch.DrawString(); the number didn't update. Is there a way to fix this?